# What is the turn of phrase for a woman who is always working/busy?

Tags: phrase-requests

I believe I heard someone refer to a woman who is always busy as a "Busy Bettie", but I can't remember the expression, and it is surprisingly relevant to my life 3 years later. It was a complimentary phrase.

Comment: Perhaps Busy **Betty**. There is a [book](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/60621131) about a character with that name, and can also mean [busybody](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busybody), an uncomplimentary phrase.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was going to answer pointing to this book, but it literally just came out. I am sure the phrase is prior to that and that it is a pun based on busy-body.

Comment: @fev I too noticed the book was October 2022 (not just now and not 3 years ago). I thought I had found a definition in [Reverso Dictionary](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/busy+Betty) but it doesn't actually, so I discarded the answer started.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are right, for some reason I thought it was this year. But it couldn't have become a best-seller overnight. Figures...

Comment: @NexGenNerd I don't see how describing someone as "always busy" is a compliment. It could mean there is stuff they neglect, like down time, friends and family.

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe they're busy because they're *not* neglecting anything, and that takes up all their time.

Comment: I doubt it's related to that book, which seems to be a children's book about a little girl.

Comment: It sounds like a woman who's trying to "have it all", but I don't think I've heard a word or phrase for this type of woman.

Comment: We have “busy bees” — but I wouldn't particularly call that a compliment.